# Wordpress Search Query Results

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a problem with my site and I'm sure it has something to do with the PHP code for the primary search function on Wordpress. Here is the site - http://romanceanimefans.com/blog/

And whenever, I make a search that has more than one page of results and click on the second page, I get an error when there are more posts to show in the results.

Here is an example of a search performed - http://romanceanimefans.com/blog/?s=search&tags[]=27&any=any

And Here is the link to the next page results - http://romanceanimefans.com/blog/page/2/?s=search

It's like there are two different search functions. What do I need to do to fix this problem?